# take content from WordPress page and deliver it to HTML via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wordpress

I have the following problem:

1. HTML blank page on server 1.
2. WordPress site on server 2.

What I need is to call the content from www.wordpress.site/sample-page/ to HTML page on server 1, but not the entire page, only the part that I can edit from wp-admin; so without header and footer.

Also, I don't know if there is any other method, but I need it to be done via JavaScript/jQuery or Ajax.

I've used Google, but is hard to get a tutorial for this, I've tried a lot of tutorials, but none is what I need, and I don't know that much JavaScript to make it work.
SO, can someone help me please?

BIG Thanks!

Andrei

L.E.:
I've found this working: http://jsfiddle.net/mdawaffe/hLWdH/

It is working as it is written, if I try to change the domain with mine, will not work.
What script do I have to implement on the server from which the content is called (taken)?

For more information, as you asked:

I have a HTML + CSS + JS template that I will use with phonegap (if you don't know about it, try it, it's very useful) to create a mobile app for Android, iOS, and BlackBerry.

Now, I have this site: `m.trafficvoice.ro` (I hope I can post links here).

In the 'live stream' page (it's called services.html), I have a HTML5 audio tag/player.
What I need, is to get from `www.trafficvoice.ro/whatever-the-name-page`, the content, but only the part that I can edit in WordPress (so without header and footer).

Why? Because in the future there will be more stream to add, and maybe some of them will be down due to unknown reason, so I need to update that page, without making an update for the entire app, upload it to the store, wait for approval, the client to download it, etc.

Big thanks!

Andrei

Comment: Since these pages are on two different servers, what you are describing won't be possible via AJAX due to the same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Is it your first time you are going to use AJAX? If so, you should give some time to yourself to learn it separately. Then you will discover that it is performed via CALLs. In this call, you will specify the page from where you want to get your info, and the place where to put it. After this, you will be able to come back here and post some code to help us help you.

Comment: Jquery has a method called .load() which does exactly what you want but for one crucial detail, it cannot (due to browser security limitations) get data from a different server.

Comment: I agree with you about the different servers issue, but I already heard about some JSONP that resolves this.

Comment: Welcome to SO Andrei!  I think you need to break this problem down into more manageable chunks.  For example, how would I retrieve the HTML?  And more than that, how would I retrieve the more _specific_ HTML that I need?  How then would I consume that HTML and send it via JS/AJAX to another server?  Also, you really should provide us more detail as to what you have already tried, rather than the blanket statements you made above.

Comment: they should really consider banning wordpress questions on SO. It's every time the same.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use an iframe instead?  You could modify a template in your theme to not display header/footer and then use that in the iframe.

Comment: I agree and would love to, but haven't reached 50 reputation.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33419/cant-add-small-comments-to-questions